# LIKES done by me on my own page don't show up anymore after making an app to post to my page's fanpage

Tags: web, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I really hope someone can tell me more about what's going on, because I spent days searching the net and for the life of me can't say what is going on.

Here's what happened. I have a website 4nieuws.nl . On every article's page I put a like button using the Javascript SDK. All worked well. On facebook I created a fanpage for the website, facebook.com/4nieuws and every now and again I would copy an interesting article there. The like button and Javascript SDK on 4nieuws.nl uses the APP Id from an app I created specifically for that purpose.

Then I thought I might automate to publish the most popular articles on the fanpage using the PHP api. I set about getting the proper authorization key using the sequence explained on this page: http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/permanent-facebook-sessions-and-posting-as-a-page

For this to work I authorized the previously mentioned app to publish on the facebook fanpages that I am admin of. And this works.

Now for the strange part. Ever since I authorized the app, if I go to 4nieuws.nl and like a page, or even 'post to facebook', the button shows 1 more like. But the like message never shows up on my personal wall. My wife, logged in to her own facebook account, gets a notification that I liked a page, but when she clicks the notification she is sent to a Facebook 404 page. When I subsequently reload the article, my 'like' is not there anymore.

Has anyone ever come across something like this ? I'm a bit anxious because I am not sure if other peoples likes on 4nieuws.nl are working as it should. I do see likes on pages but have no idea if those likes are actually registering on peoples walls.

Any help greatly appreciated.